# Angular PrimeNG: ToggleButton - set its value dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am having a PrimeNG toggle button.
I try to set if back to OFF (with function foo) it is set to ON by user.

**Template**

```
<p-toggleButton [(ngModel)]="myvar" (ngModelChange)="foo ()" onLabel="on" offLabel="off"></p-toggleButton>

output={{ myvar }}
```

**Class**

```
myvar:boolean = false;
foo ()
{
  myvar = false;
}
```

Output of myvar is always FALSE - as expected. But the setting to FALSE in foo does not affect the button itself.

Do I need to do a "refresh" or is ngModelChange not the correct callback for that??

Answer (score 0):

Using `[(ngModel)]="myvar"` means you are already using two-way binding, this means if you change the value `myvar` in the HTML the TS will be updated and vice verse.

This means you should not be using (ngModelChange)="foo ()" at all to set any value as this is already been done.

To test this try doing this:

```
foo ()
{
  console.log(this.myvar);
}
```

Now try clicking on the button to open the browser console and see if the value is already changing.